# HTML5 Canvas 4 Lines with gradient on each line point

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

since im starting with canvas, I've already figured out how to do a diamond shape, but now i need to put that diamond shape with a custom gradient from each corner

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var grd= ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,1,0,0,150);

grd.addColorStop(0, "#ff737b");
grd.addColorStop(1, "#f78c21");

ctx.moveTo(25, 25); //1ª ponto esquerda
ctx.lineTo(100, 0); //2º ponto para direita
ctx.lineTo(75, 75); //3º ponto para baixo
ctx.lineTo(25, 75); //4º ponto para esquera
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

I need this to be like this pictures
[image]
[image]

the colors are:

```
TopLeft = #ce2908
TopRight = #5a6bc6
BottomRight = #8c3173
BottomLeft = #f78c21
```

Comment: Anyone know something please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make it like so :

- Create 4 [linearGradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient), corresponding to your *top-left*, *top-right*, *bottom-right* and *bottom-left* corners.
- Make them all stop in a middle point (*here `50,50`*).
- Change their final `stop-color` to the corresponding value in `rgba`, with the alpha set to `0.1` so, the central point will be almost transparent and all the middle colors will mix together.

*Note:*
*To avoid the general transparency of the shape, you can first draw a white shape under it. To allow a full transparency across all the shape, change their first stop-color to something like `rgba(r,g,b,0.8)`.*

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var topLeft= ctx.createLinearGradient(25,25,50,50);
topLeft.addColorStop(0, "rgba(140, 49, 115, 1)");
topLeft.addColorStop(1, "rgba(140, 49, 115, .1)");

var topRight= ctx.createLinearGradient(100,25,50,50);
topRight.addColorStop(0, "rgba(90, 107, 198, 1)");
topRight.addColorStop(1, "rgba(90, 107, 198, .1)");

var bottomRight= ctx.createLinearGradient(75,75,50,50);
bottomRight.addColorStop(0, "rgba(247, 140, 33, 1)");
bottomRight.addColorStop(1, "rgba(247, 140, 33, .1)");

var bottomLeft= ctx.createLinearGradient(25,75,50,50);
bottomLeft.addColorStop(0, "rgba(206, 41, 8, 1)");
bottomLeft.addColorStop(1, "rgba(206, 41, 8, .1)");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 25); //1ª ponto esquerda
ctx.lineTo(100, 0); //2º ponto para direita
ctx.lineTo(75, 75); //3º ponto para baixo
ctx.lineTo(25, 75); //4º ponto para esquera

/* // Uncomment to avoid transparency in the middle
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  ctx.fill();
*/

ctx.fillStyle = bottomRight;
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = bottomLeft;
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = topLeft;
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = topRight;
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```